# Multiple select statements in access vba

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, select, count

I am trying to insert 2 count numbers into a table as one record in access through vba and for some reason it is saying the number of query values and destination fields are not the same when I try to run it. I am very confused why this is happening. Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
TotalVerified = " INSERT INTO Totals([TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES], [TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT]) " & _
"SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) " & _
"FROM VerifiedFormularies " & _
"AND COUNT([FORMULARY ID])" & _
"FROM ImportMetricsIDs"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the query you want is:

```
INSERT INTO Totals([TOTAL VERIFIED FORMULARIES], [TOTAL AVAILABLE FOR IMPORT]) 
    SELECT CNT1, CNT2
    FROM (SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as CNT1 FROM VerifiedFormularies) as c1 CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT COUNT([FORMULARY ID]) as CNT2 FROMImportMetricsIDs) as c2;
```

`AND` is a boolean operator, typically used in a `WHERE` clause, `ON` clause, or in an `iif()` expression.  It doesn't connect the values from two subqueries.

Comment: It says there is a `SYNTAX ERROR` in the `FROM` clause.  I think it has something to do with the `CROSS JOIN`...

Comment: @Pable . . . You can use a comma instead of `CROSS JOIN`.